# Name for number of coloops in a matroid

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, definition, matroids

**EDITED: Simpler question**

Given a matroid, a coloop is an element which belongs to all bases (equivalently, to no circuit). Is there a name for the number of coloops of a matroid? Can you please give a reference?

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION, just for the record. We can prove that the number I was asking for is actually the number of coloops**

Let $M:=\{m_1,\ldots,m_n\}$ be a finite matroid and fix one of its bases $B:=\{b_1,\ldots,b_r\}$. Then associated to $B$ there is a strict fundamental set of circuits $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^{n-r}$, so that any element of $M\setminus B$ belongs to one and only one circuit $C_i$. On the other hand, the elements of $B$ repeatedly appear in those circuits: for each $C_i$ we need some elements of $B$. But perhaps there are some elements in $B$ which are "totally independent", in the sense that they appear in no circuit at all. The "totally independent" elements of the basis are then those in $B\setminus\bigcup_i C_i$.

I think that the number of "totally independent" elements of any basis is a well defined quantity of the matroid (i.e., independent of the choice of basis). Which is the name for this quantity, and which reference can I cite?

Comment: Only ever seen this referred to as "the number of coloops".

Comment: @AaronDall Thank you. Would you say that we can safely assume that there is no well established name for this quantity?

Comment: Yes, I would say that. But maybe we can figure out a good word for it. Thinking about it for a few minutes the best word I have come up with so far is isthmusity. As you probably know matroid theory borrows lots of terminology from graph theory and an isthmus in a graph is simply a coloop in its graphic matroid.

Comment: @AaronDall I was thinking more about something like "rigidity", because if you want to pick a basis, you can be flexible about the other elements, but you must pick the "backbone" of coloops. How do you like it?

Comment: Rigidity is a term that already shows up in the matroid literature with quite a different meaning than the one you propose. Here's are some [search results](https://scholar.google.at/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=matroid+AROUND%2810%29+rigidity&btnG=).

Comment: @AaronDall Thank you, I see that there "rigidity" defines a kind of matroid, not a property of any of them, but confusion could arise. What do you think about "stiffness"?